# Get All Playlists Url Youtube

Tags: android, youtube, playlist

I have a youtube url of channel (as https://www.youtube.com/user/CNN/playlists). I try with Jsoup parse html but it gives me 30 urls of first 30 playlists. How to get all url of all playlists of this channel in Java or Android? Please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693727/youtube-api-playlist-video-restricted-to-50-how-do-i-fetch-more

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses